# Preprocessor Quoting macro arguments

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Suppose I have some macro `#define NAME name`, and I want to define some other macro which will expand to the quoted value. That is, as if I had also defined `#define NAME_STR "name"`. Is there a neater way than the following?

```
#define QUOT(str)   #str
#define QUOT_ARG(str)   QUOT(str)
#define NAME_STR    QUOT_ARG(NAME)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, due to the fact that macro arguments are not expanded when used in stringification. From the [GNU C PreProcessor manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html):

> Unlike normal parameter replacement,
>   the argument is not macro-expanded
>   first. This is called stringification.

From the same source:

> If you want to stringify the result of
>   expansion of a macro argument, you
>   have to use two levels of macros.

...which continues with an example:

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
 str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
 xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4"
```

Comment: The example is misleading: `foo` is not macro replaced to become `4` until it is used in the replacement list, so it should be `xstr (foo)` becomes `str (4)` becomes `"4"`.  To say that there is a point where you have `xstr (4)` is misleading, I think.

Comment: @James McNellis: Agreed, the example implies something along the lines of a self-referential macro, which would not be expanded afterwards. I wonder if I should edit the example or leave it, along with these comments...